# jQuery $(this).serialize() does not send unchanged input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

When I send a form using jQuery post and serialize, I only seem to send the items in the form that have been changed. I want to serialize the entire form. How do I do that?

I have some HTML.

```
<form name ="XXX" class="user_goal_form">
  <input type="hidden" name ="goalID" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name ="userID" value="1"/>
  Fullfilled: <input type="number" class="user_goal_input" name="achievedLevel" value="5"/.>
  Finished: <input type="checkbox" class="user_goal_input" name="goalCompleted" value="false"/>
</form>
```

To that is attached some jQuery:

```
$(".user_goal_input").change(function(){
  $.post("./handelform.php", {form: $(this).serialize()})
    .done(function(data) {
      $("#userList").html(data);
});
```

The content of the posted form I receive in handleform.php is only the things in the form that have changed. Never the hidden inputs or any input that has not been altered. How can I make this submit the entire form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're serializing the input instead of the form.

You can do this :

```
$(".user_goal_input").change(function(){
    $.post("./handelform.php", {form: $(this.form).serialize()})
```

Comment: Splendid. I will accept your answare later since the stipulated time from Q to A has not yet passed. Thank you.